# Get an SQL_MISUSE error when trying to sqlite3_step through a statemetn

Tags: c++, sqlite

In my c++ page, i have a preparement statement

```
sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;
```

which returns SQLITE_OK when it is passed data through the int

```
string query;
query = "select * from A;"
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,query.c_str(),0,&stmt,0);
if (SQLITE_OK != rc ){ return; }
```

function.

Then start the next line.

```
int rc;
rc = sqlite3_step(sqlstmt);
//rc = 21 here.
```

An except from the SQLITE3 documentation.  My current version is 3.07.14.01 i believe.

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html

> SQLITE_MISUSE means that the this routine was called inappropriately. Perhaps it was called on a prepared statement that has already been finalized or on one that had previously returned SQLITE_ERROR or SQLITE_DONE. Or it could be the case that the same database connection is being used by two or more threads at the same moment in time.
>
> For all versions of SQLite up to and including 3.6.23.1, a call to sqlite3_reset() was required after sqlite3_step() returned anything other than SQLITE_ROW before any subsequent invocation of sqlite3_step(). Failure to reset the prepared statement using sqlite3_reset() would result in an SQLITE_MISUSE return from sqlite3_step(). But after version 3.6.23.1, sqlite3_step() began calling sqlite3_reset() automatically in this circumstance rather than returning SQLITE_MISUSE. This is not considered a compatibility break because any application that ever receives an SQLITE_MISUSE error is broken by definition. The SQLITE_OMIT_AUTORESET compile-time option can be used to restore the legacy behavior.

**actual code function**

vector cDataInterpretor::getWorkingSet(int userID){
    vector t_val;
    vector retVal;
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;
    rc = sqlite3_open(databasePath.c_str(), &db);
    if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return t_val;
    }
    string query = "select * from insp_Assets;";
    char* errorMessage;

```
sqlite3_stmt *sqlstmt;
//rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), 0, 0, &errorMessage);

cout << "preparing statement"<<endl;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), 0, &sqlstmt, 0);
cout << "prepare code: "<<rc << endl;
if(rc != SQLITE_OK){
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return t_val;
}
cout << "Resetting call." <<endl;
rc = sqlite3_reset(sqlstmt);

cout << "about to start while"<<endl;
rc =sqlite3_step(sqlstmt);
cout << rc<<"|" << SQLITE_ROW <<"|" << SQLITE_OK <<"|"<<SQLITE_DONE<< endl;
while(rc == SQLITE_ROW){
    //sset retVal (id,name,code,typeId,reportTypeId,parentAsset);
    int id,typeID, reportTypeId;
    id = sqlite3_column_int(sqlstmt, 0);
    string name(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 1)));
    string code(reinterpret_cast<char const *>(sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 2)));
    typeID = sqlite3_column_int(sqlstmt, 3);
    reportTypeId = sqlite3_column_int(sqlstmt, 4);
    string parentAsset(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(sqlite3_column_text(sqlstmt, 5)));
    cout <<"Fetched Asset Data: "<< id <<"|"<<name<<"|"<<code<<"|"<<typeID<<"|"<<reportTypeId<<"|"<<parentAsset << endl;
    Asset a (id, name, code, typeID, reportTypeId, parentAsset);
    retVal.push_back(a);
    rc = sqlite3_step(sqlstmt);
}
cout << "while ended, about to return."<<endl;
sqlite3_close(db);
return retVal;
}
```

Comment: The `sqlite3_prepare_vb` function does not exist.  Please copy and paste *exactly* the code that fails.  Also, please include the query you have compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly calling `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`.  From the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html):

> If the nByte argument is less than zero, then zSql is read up to the
>   first zero terminator. If nByte is non-negative, then it is the
>   maximum number of bytes read from zSql. When nByte is non-negative,
>   the zSql string ends at either the first '\000' or '\u0000' character
>   or the nByte-th byte, whichever comes first.

So, your prepare statement should look like this (easiest change, at least):

```
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(
   db,
   query.c_str(),
   -1,   // instructs SQLITE to read the entire statement up to the \0 terminator
   &stmt,
   0);
```

Comment: Whose a lifesaver?   This Guy.  ^^^